# Calculating the Obj Value manually in Gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi, facility-location

I have been working on the [problem on Facility Location Problem with Gurobi using the example provided by the Gurobi team](https://colab.research.google.com/github/Gurobi/modeling-examples/blob/master/facility_location/facility_location_gcl.ipynb).

```
m = gp.Model('facility_location')

select = m.addVars(num_facilities, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='Select') # y_i
assign = m.addVars(cartesian_prod, ub=1, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='Assign') # x_ij

m.addConstrs((assign[(c,f)] <= select[f] for c,f in cartesian_prod), name='Setup2ship')
m.addConstrs((gp.quicksum(assign[(c,f)] for f in range(num_facilities)) == 1 for c in range(num_customers)), name='Demand')
m.addConstr(gp.quicksum(select[f] for f in range(num_facilities)) == 9 , name='numberoffacilities')

m.setObjective(select.prod(setup_cost)+assign.prod(shipping_cost), GRB.MINIMIZE)

m.optimize()
```

Everything is fine with the optimization programming and the result. However, I am designing an approximation algorithm to solve the problem for large instances.

In Gurobi, by using

```
obj = m.getObjective()
```

```
print(obj.getValue())
```

I can access to obj value after the accomplishment of the optimization. Moreover, the numeric result for decision variables is also provided by

```
m.getVars()
```

Now, my problem is that my approximation algorithm outputs different values for decisions variable ( different select and assignment values for nodes).

May I use the Gurobi so as to calculate the obj value of the optimization problem using the output of my approximation algorithm? In other words, I want to pass the value of the decision variables manually to Gurobi and get the obj value of the input.

Comment: Fix variables to your heuristic values and solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way to accomplish what you want is to pass your solution as a MIP Start to gurobi. If it's feasible, gurobi will report the objective value of that solution. Here is Gurobi's documentation on [MIP Start](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/examples/mip_starts.html). From the link:

> When you run the example, the MIP solver reports that the start produced a feasible initial solution:

```
User MIP start produced solution with objective 210500 (0.01s)

Loaded user MIP start with objective 210500
```